# Explaining the date code of Nichicon electrolytic capacitors

Tags: markings

I want to know how to read the date code of Nichicon brand electrolytic capacitors. For example - I have the capacitor wit date code `B1538`. So it means it was manufactured at 2015 year and 38 week? And what the letter `B` means? The datasheet can be found [here](http://products.nichicon.co.jp/en/pdf/XJA043/e-vz.pdf).

Comment: Could you link the datasheet of said capacitor? It is usually explained there.

Comment: Letters in the date code are sometimes used as an indication of which factory (when there are several possibilities) was the piece produced in.